# Contitional expectation contraction inequality two sub-sigma-algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{F}$ two $\sigma$-algebras. We know from Jensen's inequality, that for $X\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$
$$
\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{H}]|^2]\leq\mathbb{E}[|X|^2].
$$

Can this be generalized to an inequality like
$$
\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{H}]|^2]\leq\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]|^2]\leq\mathbb{E}[|X|^2]\
$$
even if $X$ is not necessarily $\mathcal{G}$-measurable?
I couldn't find a proof of that version (I don't even know if it even holds or we need further restrictions) but I'm pretty sure it was used in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06474 only justified by

> As the conditional expectation is an orthogonal projection, we clearly have that ...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  By iterated conditioning, $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal H] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal G] | \mathcal H]$ a.s. so

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal H] |^2] &= \mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal G] | \mathcal H] |^2] \\
&\le \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[ | \mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal G]|^2 | \mathcal H]] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal G] |^2]
\end{align*}

by Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way.  In $L^2$, the conditional expectation $X \mapsto \mathbb E[X|\mathcal G]$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace of $\mathcal G$-measurable functions.  Verify this.  Then your result is clear.

Also note: if $\mathcal H \subseteq \mathcal G$, then
$$
\mathbb E \big[\;\mathbb E[X|\mathcal G]\;\big|\mathcal H] = 
\mathbb E \big[\;\mathbb E[X|\mathcal H]\;\big|\mathcal G] = 
\mathbb E [X | \mathcal H]
$$
We used to say "coarse wins".